# How to pull down assets locally from S3 Bucket - via Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The only tool I could find, I forked and tried to update to include the S3_REGION because I was getting

`$ The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint`

These are all the variables I am passing to access the bucket.

```
opts[:s3_key] =======>  AKIAJHXXG*********YA
opts[:s3_secret] =======> uYXxuA*******************pCcXuT61DI7po2
opts[:s3_bucket] =======> *****
opts[:output_path] =======> /Users/myname/Desktop/projects/my_project/public/system
opts[:s3_region] =======> s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

https://github.com/rounders/heroku-s3assets has not been update in a while so Im assuming I just can't find where the actual error is breaking either in Heroku tools, or the older aws-s3 gem.

Anyone have any method to pull down production assets to Heroku server from AmazonS3?

Comment: The "s3 region" might be expecting only the region part, not the entire hostname, e.g. "s3-us-west-2" (without .amazonaws.com on the end).  I'm guessing, here.

Answer (score 1):

I think I mis-understood you, so editing now...maybe experiment with something simpler:
http://priyankapathak.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/download-assets-from-amazon-s3-via-ruby/

---

My search returned this info:

## Bucket is in a different region

> The Amazon S3 bucket specified in the COPY command must be in the same
>   region as the cluster. If your Amazon S3 bucket and your cluster are
>   in different regions, you will receive an error similar to the
>   following:

```
ERROR: S3ServiceException:The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint.
```

> You can create an Amazon S3 bucket in a specific region either by
>   selecting the region when you create the bucket by using the Amazon S3
>   Management Console, or by specifying an endpoint when you create the
>   bucket using the Amazon S3 API or CLI. For more information, see
>   Uploading files to Amazon S3.
>
> For more information about Amazon S3 regions, see Buckets and Regions
>   in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.
>
> Alternatively, you can specify the region using the REGION option with
>   the COPY command.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/s3serviceexception-error.html

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that gem was all but useless. I've gotten further to my goal of downloading all my s3 assets to public/system - but still can not figure out how to download them to my correct local rails directory using the aws s3 docs - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(access_key_id: 'AKIAJH*********PFYA', secret_access_key: 'uYXxuAMcnKODn***************uT61DI7po2', s3_endpoint: 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com')

s3.buckets['advlo'].objects.each do |obj| 
  puts obj.inspect
end
```

I probably just need to read more unix commands and scp them over individually or something. Any ideas?